# sqlsrv_fetch_array function very slow on single row

Tags: php, sql-server, performance

For some reason, any call I make to sqlsrv_fetch_array is super slow. Usually right around 18 seconds.

I can do something as simple as:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE ID = 121";
$rows = sqlsrv_query($connection,$query);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rows);
```

The query is quick, but the sqlsrv_fetch_array() takes about 18 seconds.  The row has probably 50 columns, but doesn't seem like that should effect it too much.

I also tried sqlsrv_fetch_object() but that too took 18 seconds or so.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you checked your server log for errors?

Comment: How do you connect to my(?)sql ? Is it on the same server? What is your connection string? Could be network related, localhost not pointing to 127.0.0.1 correctly, a firewall etc.

Comment: @jtheman Someone else runs the server, I'll see if they're seeing any errors. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @John I'm using sqlsrv_connect() to connect. It's a Microsoft SQL Server database and so doesn't use localhost, but I think the database is on the same server as the files. Also, it's not the actual query that's slow, it's the sqlsrv_fetch_array() which I'm guessing means the issue is something to do with PHP, though I could be wrong no that.

Comment: Also I have seen examples using (the deprecated) mssql_* instead of sqlsrv_* solving strange issues. So if you have support for mssql_ or PDO_DBLIB you might give it a shot!